# Downloading the Android OS source code and pausing the download, resulted in a huge sized and 'no source code present' working directory

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I am trying to download the Android OS source code using the official tool, that is, the **Repo** tool, by running it inside portable Git, on Windows 10, but, it seems to me that, I am not successfully progressing in downloading the source code, as, my working directory is getting of huge size, but I haven't found any source code in it, and my disk space is also getting choked.

**What is happening is:**

After I start the `repo sync` command, it seems to take some time and an amount of internet data (which is normal), but, as I have a fixed amount of internet data, I have to pause the downloading in between, which I do by pressing `CTRL+C` (based on the info I found over the Web, for pausing the downloading (because there doesn't seem to be any intended command supported by the **Repo** tool)) (Note: Although, by using `CTRL+C`, the `repo sync` command stops, I am unsure, whether that really pauses the download or cancels it, as, when I check the size of my working directory, it seems to grow after every `repo sync`).
 I have tried finding on the Web, that, how the **Repo** tool works and have also read much over the Web, that, **Repo** tool works on top of **Git** (but unfortunately, the **Repo** tool doesn't support as much commands as **Git** does), and have also read about, the structure of the source code working directory, and nearly everything related to overcoming my problem.

**The problem:**

The working directory has increased much in size, but I haven't got any source code, and that increased size is also choking my disk space. *Going in more detail*, the problem is, the contents in the 'TheWorkingDirectory > .repo > project-objects > platform > cts.git > objects > pack' and 'TheWorkingDirectory > .repo > project-objects > platform > external > deqp.git > objects > pack' folders of the working directory are the ones having huge size, so I was thinking to reduce their size, but that seems complicated enough, because, the files in those folders, don't seem very familiar to me, and also, there doesn't seem any software to see the contents of those files, and I have *not* found any way to make use of those files. Of course, when I come to know, what is in those files, then I can get rid of the not-needed ones.

**The question:**

After going through the above mentioned process of trying to download the Android OS source code, I have ended up with a working directory which is huge in size, but I can't find the source code. *And the disk space is also at the point of choking.* Can anybody help?

**And, let me emphasize the things that I am asking about. What I am asking is:**

1. Currently, how should I make use of the already existing big sized items (those items are present in my Android source code working directory [at the paths that I have mentioned in the question]), (An example of making use of them might be, like, if I can use some **Repo** and/or **Git** commands over those items to make use of them), and,
2. Currently, I **can’t** risk running `repo sync` command again because of already choked up disk space due to those big sized items being present, so all those things, mentioning, how to download a part of the source code will only be useful **after** I have, made use of the existing big sized items.

Comment: Welcone to StackOverflow. The Android source code will take up some disc space (>100GB). The git repositories are stored in the .repo folder, the actual source checkout will appear once the repo sync is complete. You can use the `--quiet` flag to only show the repo sync progress. You might be able to save some disk space by using the `--current-branch` flag for repo sync, to not download git branches you don't need. Another option is to pass `--depth=1` to repo init ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/603547/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-the-android-source-i-need-to-download-with-repo-syn)).

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 Thanks. My replies are after quoted text from your reply  _"the actual source checkout will appear once the repo sync is complete."_ The `repo sync` doesn't seem to complete, because, as I said in my question above, that because of limited internet data, I have to use `Ctrl+C` to stop `repo sync`, and I am not sure whether `repo sync` resumes from the last place I used `Ctrl+C`, when I start `repo sync` again. (See next part in the next comment)

Comment: Right, so my suggestion is to use `repo sync --quiet` so make it show the overall progress instead of the individual checkouts. Based on the progress report, you could check if it resumes from the previous run or starts fresh (I think it should resume).

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 (The next part of the above) _"You can use the --quiet flag to only show the repo sync progress. You might be able to save some disk space by using the --current-branch flag for repo sync, to not download git branches you don't need. Another option is to pass --depth=1 to repo init"_ As my disk space is choking, I can't risk starting downloading the Android source code again till some space is made. And as I also mentioned in my question, about the things that are consuming much disk space, so can you guide regarding that?

Comment: How much disc space do you have available?

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 Disk space of about 2 to 3 GBs is left on the disk, of the total disk capacity.

Comment: Ok, I think your disk space will not be enough. After `repo sync` has completed, you will need another 100 GB during the build. You could try to delete the entire `.repo` folder to start fresh, passing `--depth=1` to `repo init` and `--current-branch` to `repo sync`. But I'm pessimistic that this would save you enough space so that after `repo sync`, you have 100 GB left for the build files.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 _"You could try to delete the entire .repo folder to start fresh, passing --depth=1 to repo init and --current-branch to repo sync."_ Thanks, but can you guide about, how to use^ the **existing** huge sized contents (present at the places, I mentioned in my question), so that I may use them, as because, if I have to pause `repo sync`, then by doing that, _if_ those types of files get generated again, then it will be like starting the task again. (For what I mean by 'use', mentioned above, see my next comment.)

Comment: ^use = By 'use' (in my above comment) I mean, like, getting to know the contents of those files, and putting those contents at the appropriate place, for example, if they contain some part of the source code, then, using some method, like, one or more commands, to put their code at the appropriate place in the working directory.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 Hi, I had posted two comments in reply to your last comment, so can you guide further about my problem?